# Getting reference to WebServletContext on wildfly

Tags: soap, jax-ws, cdi, wildfly, jboss-weld

I am attempting to deploy a soap webservice on wildfly 9.0.1-Final. I try to access the WebServletContext by resource injection but it is always null. I do have a beans.xml file in WEB-INF. Following is the class definition.

loadProperties is called from the contstructor.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface =  "com.ticomgeo.interfaces._2010.geonet.healthandstatus.v2.HealthAndStatusPortType", 
portName = "HealthAndStatusPort", 
wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/classes/HealthAndStatusServiceV2.wsdl", serviceName = "HealthAndStatusService", 
targetNamespace = "http://interfaces.ticomgeo.com/2010/geonet/HealthAndStatus/v2")
@HandlerChain(file="/HandlerChain.xml")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.classificationtypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.designatortypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.basictypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.healthandstatusspecialtypes.v2.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.platformandsystemtypes.v2.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.common.signaltypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.platformantennatypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.platformandsystemresourcetypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.common.servicemessagetypes.v0.ObjectFactory.class,
    com.ticomgeo.schemas._2010.geonet.healthandstatusspecialgeoservicetypes.v2.ObjectFactory.class })
public class HealthAndStatusPortImpl extends EimWebService implements HealthAndStatusPortType {

private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(new Exception().getStackTrace()[0]
        .getClassName());
private final static Logger LOGGER=log;
private HSProperties props;
private ServiceState serviceState;
private AggregatorConnectionThread aggregatorConnectionThread;
public  String configHome=null;

  @Resource(name="wscontext")
private WebServiceContext wscontext;

public void loadProperties() {
    if (wscontext==null){
         throw new RuntimeException("wscontext = "+wscontext);
    }
```

The deployment always fails with the exception from the null test on the WebServletContext

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deploy /tmp/HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: wscontext = null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wscontext = null"},"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"HealthAndStatusServiceV2.war\".beanmanager]"]}}}
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]
```

Thank you in advance for any help

update:

Changed the resource annotation to

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wscontext;
```

but got the same result on deploy

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the @Resource name attribute (*wscontext*) then it should be properly described in your deployment descriptor(web.xml env-entry element). Otherwise you can let all this JNDI stuff generated by the app server in not specifying the name attribute at all.

Comment: Change the resource annotation to   
  @Resource
  private WebServiceContext wscontext

but got the same result on deploy

Comment: It looks like your component is instantiated with CDI but **@Resource** is not part of CDI. Do you really need WebServiceContext in the constructor? I suspect CDI instantiate your component and then delegate the **@Resource** to the app server to complete the injection. In your case if you use **@Resource** right away it might not be properly initialized yet.

Comment: I need it in the constructor to get the servlet context.  I used to be able to handle this with a servletContextListener, that worked up to and including tomcat 7.0.25. If we try to deploy on 7.0.39 the contextListener does not get invoked before the ws impl construction. Since we are switching to wildfly and there is a way to get the servlet context from the WebServletContext it seemed like a good alternative. However, I am really new to annotations. Is there another annotation I can use to force the injection of the WebServletContext? Would @Inject do it?

Comment: In That case i would create a constructor annotated with @inject taking ServletContext as parameter